# Difference between spin and rate.sleep in ROS

Tags: ros

I am new to ROS and trying to understand this powerful tool. I am confused between the `spin` and `rate.sleep` functions. Could anyone help me with the difference between these two functions and when to use each one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ros::spin()` and `ros::spinOnce()` are responsible to handle communication events, e.g. arriving messages. If you are subscribing to messages, services, or actions, you must call `spin` to process the events.

While `ros::spinOnce()` handles the events and returns immediately, `ros::spin()` blocks until ROS invokes a shutdown. So, `ros::spinOnce()` gives you more control if needed. More on that matter here: [Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

`rate.sleep()` on the other hand is merely a thread sleep with a duration defined by a frequency. Here is an example

```
ros::Rate rate(24.);
while(ros::ok())
{
    rate.sleep();
}
```

This loop will be executed 24 times a second or less, depends what you do inside the loop. A `ros::Rate` object keeps track of how much time since the last `rate.sleep()` was executed and sleep for the correct amount of time to hit the 24 Hz mark. See [`ros::Rate::sleep()`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Rate.html#ae5664d27cda1b17a103347560259e945) API.

The equivalent way in the time domain is [`ros::Duration::sleep()`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Duration.html#a39708cc9b2871f6b3715023ab9610043)

```
ros::Duration duration(1./24.);
while(ros::ok())
{
    duration.sleep();
}
```

Which one you use is just a matter of convenience.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on these two sentences: **(1)** *"... `ros::spinOnce()` handles the events and returns immediately, ..."*      **(2)** *"... `ros::spin()` blocks until ROS invokes a shutdown ... "*   especially, what did you mean by *"ROS invokes a shutdown" ?*  Did you mean killing all the nodes and eventually ROS master?  I'm still confused. Thank you so much in advance!